# Why does my Redux DevTools overwrites the start action with success action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-devtools

I'm currently having a problem wherein my useEffect() is not triggering on state change.

Upon investigating, it could have been related to what I see on my Redux DevTools,

My `FETCH_PAYMENT_METHODS_START` is being deleted, or rather being replaced by `FETCH_PAYMENT_METHODS_SUCCESS` when it should be in order with two logs.

Why is this happening?

[image]

[image]